# how to compile C++ with Raylib program in Linux terminal

Tags: c++, raylib

I created a very basic game with C++ using Raylib Package, i install Raylib from vcpkg but don't know how to compile it  can you please help me out
[Error while Compiling the Main.cpp in which my game in written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q3cp.png)

I try to compile My Main.cpp by using, g++ Main.cpp command but its giving me error
I want to Run the code and I want the GUI that Raylib package provides to play the game!

Comment: It’s better to copy the compiler’s error message as text to the question, instead of uploading an image when unnecessary. Some people might not want to click on unverified links for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I highly advise you to learn about C++ on your own at least before you post a question on StackOverflow. That being said I will answer your question:

First of all vcpkg is a package manager designed to make it easier for you to manage dependencies for a given C++ project. Vcpkg is usually used in combination with CMake (a build tool that makes it easier to generate a makefile for your C++ project).

So if you wish to use vcpkg, I highly recommend you go to the official site and look up a guide on how to use it and learn about CMake as well.

Now on to your error:
g++ is telling you exactly what is wrong. It doesn't know where to find `raylib.h` and in order for g++ to find it, you need to pass an "include flag" to it with the path to the folder where it can find the header file, i.e.:

```
g++ -I/path/to/raylib/header_folder main.cpp
```

However most likely raylib is a static/dynamic (already compiled) library so you also need to specify the path to the library so that the linker knows where to find it, i.e.:

```
g++ -I/path/to/raylib/header_folder -L/path/to/raylib/Lib_folder -lname_of_library(without lib prefix) main.cpp
```

Hope it helps!